# Using default reference object relationship to access default values for properties in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, parent-child, default-value

I have an object in a hierarchy, whose values can default to the parent object's value. Both objects are of the same type.

As an example: if the `Score` property is `double.NaN`, then the `Score` value should be retrieved from the object at which the `Parent` property points to, but only if the `Parent` is set (`Parent != null`).

My question is, how can I reliably and in a generic way, implement such a model?  I have 2 options but maybe there are more?

**Option 1:** Change each property getter and setter to check if the property being set or get has the default value, and if so, try reading it from parent

```
    private double score = double.NaN;
    public double Score
    {
        get { return (score == double.NaN && Parent != null) ? Parent.Score : score; }
        set { score = (Parent != null && Parent.Score == value) ? double.NaN : value; }
    }
```

Pros:

- real time atomic updates of all property values separately
- explicit comparisons of default values

Cons:

- each property getter and setter needs to be manually implemented, which can be error-prone
- performance is effected with each get and set

**Option 2:** Implement defaulting on object loading and saving

```
    void AfterLoad()
    {
        if(Parent != null)
        {
            if(score == double.NaN)
            {
                score = Parent.Score;
            }
            // (...)
        }
    }

    void BeforeSave()
    {
        if(Parent != null)
        {
            if(score == Parent.Score)
            {
                score = double.NaN;
            }
            // (...)
        }
    }

    void AfterSave()
    {
        AfterLoad();
    }
```

Pros:

- parent relationship is used only when loading (once) and saving (twice) which improves performance

Cons:

- at any moment parent object change will not affect child properties
- before and after changing the parent object, child needs to be processed (to fall back to the new defaults after parent changes)
- atomicity can be affected - during saving object cannot be accessed by any other thread

I am sure many have had a similar dillema when implementing an object "styling" model. I am looking for a clean and working solution which will also work with joining collections of child and parent objects together (using CompositeCollection ?).

Comment: How often does the hierarchy change?  Do you (or can you) have a `List<MyClass>` that holds all objects in the hierarchy?

Comment: @Adam: Defaults can change but not very often

Comment: Hierarchy will rarely change except adding new children to the same parent. Think of parent as a style for child. Parents are in a separate list and later can also be parents to other parents (again think of inherited styles which override parent styles for child objects).

Answer (score 1):

You can use WPF-style approach, where property values are stored not in fields, but in a dictionary in the base class.

That way all properties will look like

```
double Prop {
 get{ return (double)GetValue("Prop"); }
 set{ SetValue("Prop",value); }
}
```

And the GetValue will check all parents to find the default value if it is not set for the current class.

Comment: That's a good solution for low-volume objects, I can think of 3 limitations and problems: 1. Each access to the property require a string lookup in the base dictionary (my objects will perform heavy calculations and this might be a problem). 2. Type safety is completely and permanently lost (even generic methods will need conversion to take place internally) 3. It adds a need for maintenance of const string property names.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with a similar scenario and solved it with these two classes, i'm not completely happy with it, but maybe it helps..

```
public class RootProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public virtual T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _value)) return;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(RootProperty<T> p)
    {
        return p.Value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[RootProperty<" + typeof(T).Name + ">] " + Value;
    }
}

public class InheritedProperty<T> : RootProperty<T>
{
    private bool _override;

    public bool Override
    {
        get { return _override; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_override)) return;
            _override = value;

            //If we now override and we had no value before, copy the value that was previously inherited for convinience
            if (_override && (Value == null || Value.Equals(default(T))))
                Value = Parent.Value;

        }
    }

    public RootProperty<T> Parent { get; private set; }

    public override T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (Override)
            {
                return base.Value;
            }

            if (Parent == null)
                throw new Exception("Parent musn't be null");
            return Parent.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            Override = true;
            base.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public InheritedProperty(RootProperty<T> parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[InheritedProperty<" + typeof(T).Name + ">] " + Value;
    }
}
```

example usage

```
class TestParent
{
    public RootProperty<int> MyInt { get; private set; }

    public TestParent()
    {
        MyInt = new RootProperty<int>();
    }

}

class TestChild
{
    public InheritedProperty<int> MyInt { get; private set; }

    public TestChild(TestParent parent)
    {
        MyInt = new InheritedProperty<int>(parent.MyInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea with operator overloading seems great. I am using protobuf and/or lightspeed for (de)serialization and I'm unsure how these would behave with base types encapsulated in a *Property classes, I suppose this might work yet property.Value would need to be added everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) to organize the classes, and then store them in a single `List<MyClass>`.  Then you can use LINQ to sort and find the first non-null value for that property.  I can't speak as to it's performance, but it may be worth a shot.

The LINQ should look something like:

```
var node = myList.Where(x => x.LeftNumber <= target.LeftNumber && x.RightNumber >= target.RightNumber)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.LeftNumber)
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Prop != double.NaN);
return (node != null) ? node.Prop : double.NaN;
```

`x.LeftNumber <= target.LeftNumber && x.RightNumber >= target.RightNumber` will get the `target` node, it's parent, and all other ancestors.

The `OrderByDescending` will sort them so the bottom of the tree is first.  You can optionally use `Last()` instead of `OrderBy().First()`

`FirstOrDefault()` will get the first one that actually has a value, starting at the `target` node and working up the tree.

---

**Edit:**  Here's what I use to rebuild the tree from parent-child relationships.

```
protected static void RebuildTree()
{
    RebuildTree(allNodes[0], 0);
    SaveAllNodes();
}
private static int RebuildTree(Taxonomy node, int left)
{
    node.leftNumber = left;
    node.rightNumber = left + 1;
    foreach (Taxonomy child in node.Children)
    {
        node.rightNumber = RebuildTree(child, node.rightNumber);
    }
    return node.rightNumber + 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning Modified Preorder Tree Traversal algorithm which I did not know about. Parent-child relationship is already set so traversing it would require something like an extension method which yields all parents. My problem is how to simpify checking (and setting) if parent has the value or child has.

Comment: @too - Added code to rebuild the tree. See if that helps?  I call this code every time something changes - first I update the parent-child relationship, then call `RebuildTree()`.  `allNodes[0]` *must* be the root node.  Once you have the left/right structure in place, the LINQ above will do the checking for you.  I can throw it into a generic function which you can call, if that helps.